# Optimize parser function c program

Tags: c, optimization

```
gcc (GCC) 4.6.3 20120306 (Red Hat 4.6.3-2)
c89
```

Hello,

I am wondering if I could optimize this code anymore. As this is in a fast transactional server it will have many calls per second. So the parser has to be very quick and optimized.

I wonder if there is any improvements I could make.

The completed code with test cases included. The function `g_get_dnis_user_part` is what I want to optimize.

I hope this is the correct forum to post to.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

#ifndef FALSE
#define FALSE 0
#endif
#ifndef TRUE
#define TRUE 1
#endif

static int g_get_dnis_user_part(const char *dnis, char *user_part, size_t size);

int main(void)
{
    /* Test cases */
    const char *dnis_test1 = "0846372573@10.1.8.34";
    const char *dnis_test2 = "084637257310.1.8.34";
    const char *dnis_test3 = "084e672573@10.1.8.34";
    const char *dnis_test4 = "";
    const char *dnis_test5 = "084637257310.1.8.34@";
    size_t passes = 0;
    size_t failures = 0;

#define MAX_ADDRESS_LEN 32

    char user_part[MAX_ADDRESS_LEN];

    memset(user_part, 0, sizeof user_part);
    if(g_get_dnis_user_part(dnis_test1, user_part, MAX_ADDRESS_LEN) == TRUE) {
        printf("TEST 1 PASSED [ %s ] [ %s ]\n", dnis_test1, user_part);
        passes++;
    }
    else {
        printf("TEST 1 FAILED [ %s ] [ %s ]\n", dnis_test1, user_part);
        failures++;
    }

    memset(user_part, 0, sizeof user_part);
    if(g_get_dnis_user_part(dnis_test2, user_part, MAX_ADDRESS_LEN) == TRUE) {
        printf("TEST 2 PASSED [ %s ] [ %s ]\n", dnis_test2, user_part);
        passes++;
    }
    else {
        printf("TEST 2 FAILED [ %s ] [ %s ]\n", dnis_test2, user_part);
        failures++;
    }

    memset(user_part, 0, sizeof user_part);
    if(g_get_dnis_user_part(dnis_test3, user_part, MAX_ADDRESS_LEN) == TRUE) {
        printf("TEST 3 PASSED [ %s ] [ %s ]\n", dnis_test3, user_part);
        passes++;
    }
    else {
        printf("TEST 3 FAILED [ %s ] [ %s ]\n", dnis_test3, user_part);
        failures++;
    }

    memset(user_part, 0, sizeof user_part);
    if(g_get_dnis_user_part(dnis_test4, user_part, MAX_ADDRESS_LEN) == TRUE) {
        printf("TEST 4 PASSED [ %s ] [ %s ]\n", dnis_test4, user_part);
        passes++;
    }
    else {
        printf("TEST 4 FAILED [ %s ] [ %s ]\n", dnis_test4, user_part);
        failures++;
    }

    memset(user_part, 0, sizeof user_part);
    if(g_get_dnis_user_part(dnis_test5, user_part, MAX_ADDRESS_LEN) == TRUE) {
        printf("TEST 5 PASSED [ %s ] [ %s ]\n", dnis_test5, user_part);
        passes++;
    }
    else {
        printf("TEST 5 FAILED [ %s ] [ %s ]\n", dnis_test5, user_part);
        failures++;
    }

    printf("ALL TEST COMPLETED PASSES [ %ld ] FAILURES [ %ld ]\n", passes, failures);

    return 0;
}

/* Get the user part from the complete dnis number
   0846372573@10.1.8.34 -> 0846372573 nul terminated */
static int g_get_dnis_user_part(const char *dnis, char *user_part, size_t size)
{
    size_t i = 0;
    int status = FALSE;

    /* Make room for the nul terminator */
    if(size > 1) {
        size--;
    }
    else {
        return status;
    }

    for(i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        /* Check for valid digit */
        if(isdigit(*dnis) != 0) {
            user_part[i] = *dnis;
        }
        else {
            if(*dnis == '@') {
                /* We are at the end */
                status = TRUE;
                break;
            }
            else {
                /* Not a digit or @ - corrupted dnis string */
                status = FALSE;
                break;
            }
        }

        /* Next character */
        dnis++;
    }

    /* nul terminate the string */
    user_part[i++] = '\0';

    /* Status FALSE indicates that the @ was not found or possible corruption with dnis string */
    return status;
}
```

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: Sounds to me like a better fit for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Have you profiled to make sure that the function you are trying to optimize really is the bottleneck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I'd write the parser more like this:

```
static int g_get_dnis_user_part2(const char *dnis, char *user_part, size_t size)
{
    if (size == 0)
        return FALSE;

    size_t i;

    for (i=0; i<size-1 && isdigit(dnis[i]); i++)
        user_part[i] = dnis[i];
    user_part[i] = '\0';
    return (dnis[i] == '@') ? TRUE : FALSE;
}
```

If you really want to, you can also change the call to `isdigit` to something like `my_isdigit`, which you'd implement something like this:

```
int my_isdigit(int input) {
    static char table[UCHAR_MAX+1];
    bool inited;

    if (!inited) 
        for (int i='0'; i<'9'; i++)
            table[i] = 1;

    return table[input];
}
```

I've tried to keep that clean, but to make it a tiny bit faster, do the initialization explicitly (and separately) so you don't check whether it's initialized every character. (but with decent branch prediction, that won't gain much).

Other than that, as others have already mentioned, I'd change the definitions of `TRUE` and `FALSE` -- the ones you're using strike me as pretty awful. Conventionally, FALSE=0 and TRUE=1, and don't see where changing those has gained you anything useful at all.

Answer (score 4):

Don't over-optimize. This is a very simple function that operates on a dataset small enough to fit in cache. Chances are it's running pretty much as fast as it can already (assuming optimized compiler flags, etc). But more importantly, this is going to be only a tiny part of your overall program. Don't spend all your effort rewriting this in assembler and poring over x86 architecture manuals to make sure the CPU pipeline is kept perfectly full or whatever when you're sure to have much more low-hanging fruit elsewhere. Profile first, then optimize where the profiler says you're too slow.

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
if(isdigit(*dnis) != 0)
```

with

```
if ( *dns>='0' && *dns<='9' )
```

if you are concerned only about decimal digits and dont bother about [locales](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/basedefs/xbd_chap07.html)

Though not significant, the function call overhead will be saved. ( You need to verfy whether this is impacting *significantly*) Apart from this I don't see any major changes to be done.

Answer (score 1):

I basically agree with bdonlan, don't overoptimize and measure if you have a doubt. I would even go further than that. If I understand your algorithm correctly, what you are doing is to check the initial segment of your string for decimal characters and then check if the following character is a `@`.

- `strspn` is there at your disposal for checking for a whole class of characters, just use it.
- the check the following character for `'@'`

That's it.

gcc has `strspn` as builtin, I don't think that you can do much better, having in mind that the bottleneck of your run will be to suck all the strings from memory. Once they are in cache, you shouldn't feel much of a difference.

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you can benefit from unrolling your loop. It won't be too pretty but something along the lines like this should work (untested):

```
#define CHECKDIGIT(d, user_part, status) \
do {\
    if(isdigit(*(d)) != 0) {    \
        *(user_part)++ = *(d)++;\
    }                           \
    else {                      \
        if(*(d) == '@') {       \
            (status) = TRUE;    \
            goto finish;        \
        }                       \
        else {                  \
            (status) = FALSE;   \
            goto finish;        \
        }                       \
    }                           \
} while(0)

static int g_get_dnis_user_part(const char *dnis, char *user_part, size_t size)
{
    size_t i = 0;
    int status = FALSE;
    int chunks, rem;

    /* Make room for the nul terminator */
    if(size > 1) {
        size--;
    }
    else {
        return status;
    }

    // Divide size in chunks of 8
    chunks = size >> 3;
    rem = size & 0x7;

    for(i = 0; i < chunks; i++) {
        /* Check for valid digit */
        CHECKDIGIT(dnis, user_part);
        CHECKDIGIT(dnis, user_part);
        CHECKDIGIT(dnis, user_part);
        CHECKDIGIT(dnis, user_part);
        CHECKDIGIT(dnis, user_part);
        CHECKDIGIT(dnis, user_part);
        CHECKDIGIT(dnis, user_part);
        CHECKDIGIT(dnis, user_part);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < rem; i++) {
        CHECKDIGIT(dnis, user_part);
    }

    finish:
    /* nul terminate the string */
    user_part[i++] = '\0';

    /* Status FALSE indicates that the @ was not found or possible corruption with     dnis string */
    return status;
}
```